# Google sheets Script to add a precentage to entire column

Tags: function, google-sheets, scripting

Hey I can't seem to be able to write this script sucssefully.

I want that when I press a button a certain percentage value will be added to an entire column.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KLvgW0HBZg0spWp8osskl1LgR3sslxScI4E9w1OBKfg/edit?usp=sharing
Link to the sheet itself.

**what i want is to add the value in K2 to the entire B column by clicking the button on L2**

Here is the code I tried to do:

```
function  increase(){
    ModifyCell("B2:B","L2","I1")
}

function ModifyCell(CellName, increase,precentage) {
   var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var r = s.getActiveCell();
      if( r.getColumn() == 2 && r.getValue()>0)
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      nextCell.setValue(r.getValue()+r.getValue()*increase-r.getValue() *increase*precentage);
}
```

Comment: Could you please give more details on your purpose? What button, what percentage and what column are you talking about? I don't think you've made that clear.

Comment: @lamblichus i edited the question can you please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to do the following:

- When the button in `L2` is pressed, increase each `Amount` in column B with the percentage specified on `K2`. That is to say. If the original amount in `B2` is 3,000 and `K2` is 10%, the new amount would be 3,300.

If that's the case, you can do this:

```js
function increase() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var destRange = s.getRange(2, 2, s.getLastRow() - 1); // Column B
  var percentage = s.getRange("K2").getValue();
  var destValues = destRange.getValues();
  destValues = destValues.map(row => [row[0] * (1 + percentage)]);
  destRange.setValues(destValues);
}
```

#### Note:

- Make sure the button in `L2` is attached to `increase`.
- In the code you provided, you were providing the A1 notations of the different ranges (`B2:B`, `L2`), but these are not the ranges themselves. You should have used [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation).

#### Reference:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows)

Comment: @GamingWorld You're welcome. Glad your issue was fixed.